# Maintaining multiple UEFI partitions

Tags: grub, uefi

Currently, I have 6 internal drives with 6 different OSes (Windows, Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian, OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, Arch Linux) installed on each of them. Each drive has its own EFI partition, so that I can detach the hard drive and reattach them irrespective of the other drives in the system. So, in a way, each drive has a self-contained OS in it. All of them are connected through SATA.

However, sometimes, when one drive is unplugged, and the later plugged in the system, the EFI entry does not automatically show up. What is the remedy for this?

I am using GRUB for all Linux installations, except Arch, which uses reFIND. This problem never happens with Windows, and it always shows up in UEFI whenever it is plugged in.

System specifications:

- Motherboard: Asus Strix X370-F motherboard
- SSD: Crucial MX500 2.5"
  drive

Comment: You'll have to configure the auto-mount settings for each of the systems

Comment: Its often an UEFI issue. When a drive is disconnected it forgets the UEFI entry. If you look with `sudo efibootmgr -v` your will see entry changes and is not an UEFI entry. Most UEFI do find "Windows Boot Manager" and Some find Fedora's entry Most should boot from the fallback entry or drive entry which all external drives use or /EFI/bootx64.efi in ESP. I just add entries to my 40_custom for main working install that I always boot and if external drive is present that entry works, otherwise grub fails, and reverts back to menu or boots first entry or crashes (not always consistent).

Comment: `EFI entry does not automatically show up` ... where?

Comment: @jsotola in UEFI